# OneToMany Composite Key not generated

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Spring Security and for that I have a User and a Role class.
The users's roles are stored in a Join Table User_Role.
I've managed to have Hibernate autobuild everything fine for me, but the Primary Key is not composite (I can only add the user or the role a single time).

The "User" class:

```
@Entity(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;
    private String password;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;
    private boolean enabled;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Role.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "USER_ROLE", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID") })
    private Set<Role> roles;
// Getters and Setters
```

The "Role" Class:

```
@Entity(name = "role")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @Column(unique=true)
    private String name;
// Getters and Setters
```

Database structure:
[image: Database Structure generated]

The Error I'm getting is:

[image: Error]

How can I add several Roles for my User without modifying the sctructure too much?

Comment: *How can I add several Roles for my User without modifying the structure too much?* you have to change the unique constraint to be the multiple columns that should be considered duplicate. It is that simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking on a ManyToMany relationship, and not a OneToMany.

One user can have multiple roles, but each role in your table can apply to multiple users.

Comment: That's a stupid thing I did. Yeah, I was looking at the table structure (which was not very clear) and forgot about the ManyToMany thing.Thanks!